# Refresh RecyclerView in TabLyout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have Activity with `LastTransactionsFragment`, this fragment contains `TabLayout` with 3 tabs (`AllTransactionsFragment` , `IncomesTransactionsFragment` and `OutgoesTransactionsFragment`). All the tabs shows `RecyclerView` with list of transactions. User can delete row in each fragments. I need to implement if user delete row in 2nd fragment it also delete it immediately in 1st fragment. For now it delete row in main fragment and in database, but not in others fragments. It changes when i move to other and go back. All fragments look the same:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_transactions_list, container, false);

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        ArrayList<TransactionModel> lastTransactionsList = databaseHelper.getAllTransactionList();
        Collections.reverse(lastTransactionsList);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_allTransactionsList);

        adapter = new LastTransactionsAdapter(getContext(), lastTransactionsList, false);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return view;
    }
```

EDIT

here is short video of the issue: https://streamable.com/398zke

EDIT 2

On Fragment with TabLayout

```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
              if (position== 0){
                  IncomesTransactionsListFragment fragment = new IncomesTransactionsListFragment();
                  fragment.refreshRecyclerView();
              } else if (position == 1){
                  AllTransactionsListFragment allTransactionsListFragment = new AllTransactionsListFragment();
                  allTransactionsListFragment.refreshRecyclerView();
              } else  if (position == 2){
                  AllTransactionsListFragment allTransactionsListFragment = new AllTransactionsListFragment();
                  allTransactionsListFragment.refreshRecyclerView();
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

and the method in each fragments:

```
 public void refreshRecyclerView(){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

EDIT 3 
main fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_last_transactions, container, false);

        final ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.vp_allTransactions);
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tl_allTransactions);

        adapter = new TransactionsViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
              if (position == 0){
                  IncomesTransactionsListFragment fragment = new IncomesTransactionsListFragment();
                  System.out.println(0);
                  fragment.refreshRecyclerView();

              } else if (position == 1){
                  AllTransactionsListFragment allTransactionsListFragment = new AllTransactionsListFragment();
                  System.out.println(1);
                  allTransactionsListFragment.refreshRecyclerView();

              } else  if (position == 2){
                  AllTransactionsListFragment allTransactionsListFragment = new AllTransactionsListFragment();
                  System.out.println(2);
                  allTransactionsListFragment.refreshRecyclerView();

              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

tab fragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_transactions_list, container, false);

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        ArrayList<TransactionModel> lastTransactionsList = databaseHelper.getAllTransactionList();
        Collections.reverse(lastTransactionsList);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_allTransactionsList);

         adapter = new LastTransactionsAdapter(getContext(), lastTransactionsList, false);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshRecyclerView(){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using notifyDataSettChanged() in onResume() if your all code is here in the onCreateView() then this will be called only once.

Comment: I tried. Where should I use it? in onResume?

Comment: It doesnt work. Here its short video of the issue: https://streamable.com/398zke

Comment: Thanks for sharing the video, Use view pager addOnPageChangeListener to update the fragment data. Write this method in your activity. You can first take reference of your fragment inside onPageSelected(int pos) and then call the fragments method to refresh the recycler view.

Comment: Ok, I thought about it. I know that I should hange the onPageSelected method. Should i gat adapter from other fragment and call notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: you're creating a new fragment in the `onPageSelected` and calling refresh on it. You need to get the already active fragment in the `tabLayout` and call refresh on that

Comment: @Saurabh how to do that?

Comment: Look at `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: is it adapter.getItem?

Comment: I found this  `Fragment item = adapter.getItem(0);` I can cast it to right fragment, I did it and tried to call refresh method but it didnt work to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the addOnPageChangeListener() to update any fragments data from activity. for ex.

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetpxl) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           /*get your fragments instance and write one method in that fragment to refresh the list. call this method from here*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Use this link for reference: https://www.legendblogs.com/blog/how-to-use-tablayout-in-viewpager-with-recyclerview/121810

Comment: Could you look on my new edit? I added the method but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Do you get the call in the newly created method refreshRecyclerView() ? if yes then before calling notifyDataSetChanged in the method. set the adapter with changed data from database.

Comment: I'm completly lost. I edited my post for the last time with whole code of example tab fragment and main fragment. If you could have a look.